# edit json file don't libary

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript

I have such a file: `test.json`

contents:

```
[
  {
    "data_on": {
      "vals_e": "",
      "vals_o": ""
    },
    "data_off": {
      "vals_d": ""
    }
  }
]
```

I want to immediately delete everything in `test.json` on request and write the new data. They will be correct JSON

How can I do that?
on demand that all content is removed from the file. And new data would be written.

Answer (score 0):

As this question tagged with Nodejs I suggest you may use it to read/write the file. Just open the file with `w` flag, once you start write things into the file object it will ignore all the content it used to contain.

You may want to read [this](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsopenpath-flags-mode-callback).